# Java Swing and HTML

Tags: java, swing, jsp

I am currently trying to upload Java Table(JTable) onto a JSP page. Can anybody give me suggestions on how to achieve this? I currently using this for my JSP page.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="javaPackage.Table" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
      <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
          <title>Telus Database</title>
      </head>

      <body>
          <div>
<%
Table table = new Table("tableName");

%>
          </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

And I use JFrame inside of the Table class, but when I enter this webpage, it causes the web to make a popup of the Table and I don't want that. I want the table to be on the page. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help. 
NOTE: I have to use Java Swing since the previous writer used it to upload the datas from the mysql database with JDBC and tomcat apache.

Comment: In my time with JSP, I don't recall ever using a Swing element. I recall converting the table over to HTML. If it needs Table-style controls, you might need a framework.

Comment: You should indent your code. In addition to just being good practice, it'll help you spot errors quickly and help those who want to help see errors.

Comment: @Compass Yes I am well aware that it is better to use HTML tables, but it is currently using Tomcat and JDBC to upload datas from my mysql database.

Comment: Is there a reason the table can't be created on a Servlet and delivered as data for the JSP?

Comment: well it still causes it to be a pop up. The table won't physically embed into the page

Comment: You can embedded Swing components in HTML like this. You have, at least, two choices, you could use a JApplet instead, but that brings its own bag of issues or you could create a HTML table from your data

Answer (score 0):

I'd still try to render this into an HTML table, but if you must use swing:

1. [try writing an applet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/), or
2. [Render the swing components on the server](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/04/20/bringing-swing-to-the-web.html). The gist of it is that you render the swing component to an image on the server (so, off-screen), and then send the rendered image to the page. It's an interesting trick, but the user won't be able to interact with the JTable.

Comment: For the option 2, you are talking about swingworker? I'm not still quite familiar with this servlet so I'm not quite sure where to start. Am I supposed to put all the data rendering on doPost method?

Comment: for option 2, that would be on a doGet where you will return an image. The HTML will have an <img> tag, with the src attribute pointing to the servlet serving this image. You may want to make a HTML-only page, though. nothing in your use-case says it's Swing-only.